# Amazon - point your elastic IP to a VPC peer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

I can't seem to be able to find an answer to this question within the Amazon documentation.

Let's say my account has an elastic IP. It is now assigned to an instance within a VPC. I then start a VPC peering request with a VPC belonging to another account. After the request is completed, I have connectivity between the two VPCs.

My question: Can I now assign my elastic IP to an instance residing on the peer VPC, even though it belongs to another Amazon account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I now assign my elastic IP to an instance residing on the peer
>   VPC, even though it belongs to another Amazon account?

No, this is not possible.

The only way you may be able to approximate this is to set up routing rules and 1:1 NAT on your EIP VPC instance so that it can NAT traffic to the instance required in the second VPC.